# Google Foobar number_station_coded_messages

Tags: python, list

I am trying to complete a google foo.bar level 2 challenge titled "number_station_coded_messages". Here is the problem:

> Given a non-empty list of positive integers l and a target positive integer t, write a function answer(l, t) which verifies if there is at least one consecutive sequence of positive integers within the list l (i.e. a contiguous sub-list) that can be summed up to the given target positive integer t (the key) and returns the lexicographically smallest list containing the smallest start and end indexes where this sequence can be found, or returns the array [-1, -1] in the case that there is no such sequence (to throw off Lambda's spies, not all number broadcasts will contain a coded message).
>
> For example, given the broadcast list l as [4, 3, 5, 7, 8] and the key t as 12, the function answer(l, t) would return the list [0, 2] because the list l contains the sub-list [4, 3, 5] starting at index 0 and ending at index 2, for which 4 + 3 + 5 = 12, even though there is a shorter sequence that happens later in the list (5 + 7). On the other hand, given the list l as [1, 2, 3, 4] and the key t as 15, the function answer(l, t) would return [-1, -1] because there is no sub-list of list l that can be summed up to the given target value t = 15.
>   To help you identify the coded broadcasts, Bunny HQ has agreed to the following standards:
>
> - Each list l will contain at least 1 element but never more than 100.
> - Each element of l will be between 1 and 100.
> - t will be a positive integer, not exceeding 250.
> - The first element of the list l has index 0.
> - For the list returned by answer(l, t), the start index must be equal or smaller than the end index.
>
> Remember, to throw off Lambda's spies, Bunny HQ might include more than one contiguous sublist of a number broadcast that can be summed up to the key. You know that the message will always be hidden in the first sublist that sums up to the key, so answer(l, t) should only return that sublist.

Below is my current solution.

```
def answer(l, t):
    for index1, value1 in enumerate(l):
        for index2, value2 in enumerate(l):
            if sum(l[index1:index2]) == t:
                return [index1, index2 -1]

    return [-1, -1]
```

I am able to pass 4/5 test cases but I fail on Test 5. I am not sure what it fails against? I am not necessarily looking for a solution so much as test cases that this does fail against! I was able to find a [java solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40695207/google-foobar-numbers-station) but sadly, I know nothing about java! Any help or tips are greatly appreciated!

Comment: @StefanPochmann Can a solution being inefficient cause you to not pass a certain test case? I was unaware that is how it worked.

Comment: Yes, of course. Efficiency is important.

Comment: Given that this is Google's automated hiring screening, do you think this counts as cheating?

Comment: It might be cheating. There are plenty of people that ask for help on these challenges though. Being that I am not looking for a job from, nor could I get a job, from google I am not worried about asking for help.

Comment: What about this condition? "returns the lexicographically smallest list containing the smallest start and end indexes where this sequence can be found"

Answer (score 1):

```
def answer(x,y):
    a=[-1,-1]
    c=list(x)
    for keyi,i in enumerate(c):
        for keyj,j in enumerate(c):
            if sum(x[keyi:keyj+1]) == y:
                return [keyi, keyj]
    return a
```

slight problem in the iteration missed the last element in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a test case you fail:

```
>>> answer([1, 2, 3], 6)
[-1, -1]
```

It's also extremely inefficient. Should be O(n). Or at least O(n<sup>2</sup>). Yours is only O(n<sup>3</sup>). Try it with a list of let's say 10000 numbers and an unreachable target.

Comment: Later in the description it says the largest the list can be is 100 elements. Is it possible that it just times out and I fail?

Comment: Please give us the whole problem then, not only parts.

Comment: I apologize, the readme for the problem is quite long and I was trying to minimize what was in my question. I will edit my question with more information.

Comment: @JoshuaDay With size 100 it's probably not the speed, so I looked more closely and added a small test case you fail.

Comment: Thank you! A combination of your answer and You Ssef's answer helped me solve it! Now that I have solved the problem, would you mind showing me or giving me a hint towards a more efficient solution? I dont have much knowledge when it comes to that kind of thing.

Comment: @JoshuaDay O(n^2) is easy, just don't compute every sum from scratch. Use the current sum to compute the next sum. O(n) is a bit harder, use prefix sum differences and a hash table.

Answer (score 0):

I though about it for a bit and I think I have a test case.
Keep in mind that the `sum` of an empty list is zero.

Your inner for loop iterates over the entire list no matter where the outer loop is.
Take for example the list `[4, 2]` with 4 as a target, when both loops are in the same index (0), `sum(l[0:0])` is equal to zero. However, because there is another element in the list, in the next loop `sum(l[0:1])` is indeed equal to 4, and you return `[index1, index2 - 1]` which would be `[0, 0]`, so no problems here.

if there aren't anymore elements than the 4, our list would be just `[4]`, you fall into a problem. The right answer here is `[0, 0]` but your code would not return that because, as I said before, `sum(l[0:0])` is always equal to zero. Your condition is never satisfied, and you'll return `[-1, -1]`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the optimized solution!

```
def solution(l,t):
    sum=0
    j=0
    for keyi,i in enumerate(l):
        sum = sum + i
        print(sum)
        while(sum>t and j < keyi ):
            sum = sum - l[j]
            j = j + 1
        if sum == t:
            return [j,keyi]

    return [-1,-1]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code dumps without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your question and explain how it works better than what the OP provided.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another efficient solution

```
def solution(l, t):
# Your code here
a = [-1,-1]

for index1,i in enumerate(l):
    #initial sum value
    total_sum = 0
    
    for index2,j in enumerate(l):
        total_sum = sum(l[index1:index2+1])
        if total_sum == t:
            return [index1,index2]
            
        if total_sum > t:
            break
return a
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here's more efficent code whtime complexity is O(n)**

```
def solution(l, t):
    def solution(arr, t, dic):
        prefix_sum = 0
        dic[prefix_sum] = -1 
        
        for i, num in enumerate(arr):
            prefix_sum += num
            
            if prefix_sum - t in dic:
                return [dic[prefix_sum - t] + 1, i]  
            
            dic[prefix_sum] = i  
        
        return [-1, -1] 

    return(solution(l, t, {}))
```